# grunt-contrib-<pluginName> packages are officially supported by Grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs, r.js, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I'm about to use the RequireJs plugin for Grunt. I found out that there are two plugins with the same functionality:

- grunt-contrib-requirejs (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs)
- grunt-requirejs (https://github.com/asciidisco/grunt-requirejs)

I am wondering if **-contrib** prefixed plugins are the trusted, maintained and officially supported ones by Grunt? Is this a pattern that developers should look for?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question but a question about how the Grunt maintainers manage their project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the grunt-contrib-* naming convention is for official grunt plugins.
See here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib